# Display entries by tag

Tags: tags

I've read through the docs but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

**I'd like to display a list of entries by tag, where the tag is in segment 2 of the url.**

Here's what I've tried and is not working (they output nothing):

```
{% set secondSegment = craft.app.request.getSegment(2) %}

{% set diaryEntries = craft.entries.section(['gardenDiary','gardenInfo']).relatedTo({
        sourceSite: craft.app.sites.currentSite.id, 
    element: secondSegment,
    field: 'gardenTags'
}).limit(null).all() %}
```

Also tried:

```
{% set diaryEntries = craft.entries.section('gardenDiary').relatedTo(secondSegment).all() %}
```

...

```
{% for entry in diaryEntries %}
{{ entry.title }}
...etc...
{% endfor %}
```

- Entries are known to be related to tags
- I've tried adding a known related tag directly - still nothing.
- If I don't specify a tag, it lists all the entries.
- Example URL: mydomain.com/tags/fruit
- Template is loaded via a Route: [Global] tags/* -->  tags/index.html

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `relatedTo` param expects an object, an ID or an array of object or ID ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter)), in your case `secondSegment` is a string and this is the issue. Try:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.slug( craft.app.request.getSegment(2) ).one() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).all() %}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works.