# Fetch Entries with Tags Only

Tags: craft3, entry, php, tags, yii

I'm trying to get all the entries which have tags associated with them.

At the moment I'm doing:

```
$entries = Entry::find()->with('tags')->all();
```

and then filtering the results in PHP as follows:

```
$filteredEntries = array_filter($entries, function($entry) {
    return count($entry['tags']) > 0;
});
```

This works fine, but I am still fetching all the entries, even without tags from the DB - I think this can be more efficient if I can specify in my query that I only want the entries with tags associated to them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `relatedTo` parameter ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#relatedto)) and [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/32950/display-entries-by-tag/32963#32963) will also help.

If you wanted to return any entries which has (any) tags attached, you could do:

```
$entries = Entry::find()->tags(':notempty:')->all();
```

Where `tags` is the handle of your tags field.

Comment: I've used the `relatedTo` parameter when trying to find a post with a specific tag - for example `Entry::find()->relatedTo($tag)->all();` where `$tag` is a particular tag - how would I abstract this to find a post with any tag though?

Comment: Just edited my answer above.